# Invoke-Command inside wpf button click event does not return output to PowerShell console

Tags: wpf, powershell

I have a WPF form and if I place an `Invoke-Command` inside the button click event then it does not return any output to console. If I place it outside the button click event it works fine.

I have tried `-Verbose` switch but that did not work. I have tried capturing output to a variable and writing it to console but that did not work either.

WPF Button:

```xml
<Button x:Name="pg_CopyFile_btn_Copy" Content="Copy" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="286,354,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="153" Height="39"/>
```

Button click event:

```bsh
$wpf.pg_CopyFile_btn_Copy.add_Click({
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ServerName -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock {
        Get-Process
    }
})
```

Tried this, but it did not work:

1. ```
   $wpf.pg_CopyFile_btn_Copy.add_Click({
       Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ServerName -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock {
           $Processes = Get-Process;
           Write-Output $Processes
       }
   })
   ```
2. ```bsh
   $wpf.pg_CopyFile_btn_Copy.add_Click({
       $Processes = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ServerName -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock {
           Get-Process
       }
       Write-Output $Processes
   })
   ```

I expected it to output all the processes from the remote computer on the PowerShell console.

Comment: Without more knowledge about the rest of the code, I would like to share a potential pitfall when mixing .net code and powershell through events. Although the code seems to work, the reality is that they don't share the same runspace and things become difficult. The most common and known not working solution is the `[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}` when instead of `$true` you add a powershell function.

Comment: GUI applications don’t have a console. There is no standard output. You could add a textbox to the form and have the results output there. See [Displaying Output in a GUI Application](https://www.sapien.com/blog/2014/12/15/display-output-in-a-gui-application-copy/)

Comment: @Theo Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I was looking for. I am appending everything to a textbox and its working fine. Only issue is GUI gets updated at the end when script has finished. Is there a way I can refresh GUI screen, so its having latest data?

Comment: For that we need to see some of your code.